# fabric8 on GKE via gofabric8: no Ingress or credentials?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, fabric8

I installed Fabric8 on a Google Container Engine cluster and I used `gofabric8 deploy` with a custom domain and cd-pipeline app to install fabric8.io on it. It seems to be running if I do `kubectl get pods`, but how can I access it? I tried the public IP from the loadbalancer, no hail yet. I looked at the forwarding rules in GKE and I added 443 next to 80 which was already there, no effect. Then I looked at the Ingress (`kubectl get ing`) and there is none. What am I missing and how can I fix it? Am I doing something strange and unsupported?

Answer (score 1):

We had an issue with the Ingress controller pod which looks like it's been fixed but I've not had a chance to try it out yet https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/issues/34

So for now we've been using the Google Container loadbalancer as it automatically creates external IPs for our services.  We've just updated our GKE docs so hopefully things are a bit clearer.  From the docs we've also linked to a silent demo of running fabric8 with CD pipelines etc on GKE so that might help too.

http://fabric8.io/guide/getStarted/gke.html

FWIW to access the fabric8 console we use a service proxy from the Kubernetes API server, the console inself then uses either ingress or external ips to access Jenkins, Gogs, Nexus etc

```
https://$KUBERNETES_SERVER/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/default/services/fabric8/
```

Comment: To get the external ip's from the CLI rather than the fabric8 console you can run `kubectl get services` and get the external ip address for each service.  They can take a minute to create and you also need to watch out incase you exceed your GKE quotas, these can be checked in the GKE dashboard.  We've added a section to the docs that helps delete old static ips and forwarding rules http://fabric8.io/guide/getStarted/gke.html#google-container-engine-quotas

Comment: FWIW we've now added support for the Kubernetes Ingress Controller which means we automatically deploy an NGINX ingress controller and generate the Ingress Rules when you use gofabric8 v0.4.42.  We just added a blog which explains things in more detail: https://blog.fabric8.io/accessing-your-applications-on-kubernetes-or-openshift-3e69be0ad3bc#.j6dtvhbyo